# How filter specifics URL's on my filter that implements ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter?

Tags: java, filter, java-ee-7

I am implementing a Filter like below:

```
@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
       System.out.print("request");
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
       System.out.print("response");
    }

}
```

How do I make the filter work only for URL's that follow a certain pattern (regexp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not allowed in a filter - some wildcards are

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>...</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name> MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Employee/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You can narrow down the URLs using a Filter then inside your filter Java code, you can use RegEx for conditional processing

Comment: It was I did! Thanks!